# Stage dimensions in a new NativeWindow

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs6

i'm building a flash desktop App where the user clicks on a button and opens a SWF file (a game) in a new window, i used a NativeWindow to achieve it, i did the folowing:

```
var windowOptions:NativeWindowInitOptions = new NativeWindowInitOptions();
windowOptions.systemChrome = NativeWindowSystemChrome.STANDARD;
windowOptions.type = NativeWindowType.NORMAL;

var newWindow:NativeWindow = new NativeWindow(windowOptions);
newWindow.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
newWindow.stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
newWindow.bounds = new Rectangle(100, 100, 2000, 800);

newWindow.activate();
var aLoader:Loader = new Loader;
aLoader.load(new URLRequest(path));
newWindow.stage.addChild(aLoader);
```

the result is this:
[image]
the game doesn't take the whole space available. When i change the "NO_SCALE" to "EXACT_FIT":

```
newWindow.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
```

i got this:
[image]

it only shows the top-left corner of the game. I also tried "SHOW_ALL" and "NO_BORDER". I got the same result as "EXACT_FIT".
When i open the SWF file of the game separatly it's displayed normally:

[image]

any idea how can i display the SWF game as the image above?

Comment: Load SWF **before** you create the new window and put the loaded content there. Because initially **Loader** is empty and has dimensions of 0x0 hence the scaling problems.

Comment: I tried to load the SWF before creating the window, but the problem persists.

Comment: @أسامةالزاهد, did you find any solution to your problem ? If you see when your game is loaded, then the application container just assumes default size of 375X500 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for that is to have the dimensions of your external game in pixel. you have to stretch the loader to fit it in your stage. if you are try to load different games with different sizes to your stage, save the swf dimensions with their URL addresses.

```
var extSWFW:Number = 550;
var extSWFH:Number = 400;
var extURL:String = "./Data/someSwf.swf";

var mainStageWidth:Number = 1024;
var mainStageHeight:Nubmer = 768;

var aLoader:Loader = new Loader;
aLoader.load(new URLRequest(extURL));
newWindow.stage.addChild(aLoader);

aLoader.scaleY = aLoader.scaleX = Math.min(mainStageWidth/extSWFW,mainStageHeight/extSWFH);
```

Comment: i have a lot of games to load, i don't know all of their dimensions, so how can i use your approach to solve my problem? do i need to get the dimensions of all of them?

Comment: Yes, I did something like that before. I stored all dimension close to the game's url address.
But, for an other project, I had source files of the games to. I add a rectangle match to the back ground of each game's stages on the first frame of them to get the swf dimension by using loader.content.width (be cause you are not able to get the external swf's stage.stageWidth without magic!)

Answer (score 0):

It is not **very** difficult to figure dimensions of a loaded SWF because it is engraved into it's header, you can read and parse it upon loading. Here's the working sample:

```
package assortie 
{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class Dimensions extends Sprite
    {
        private var loader:Loader;

        public function Dimensions() 
        {
            super();

            loader = new Loader;
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

            loader.load(new URLRequest("outer.swf"));
        }

        private function onLoaded(e:Event):void
        {
            var aBytes:ByteArray = loader.contentLoaderInfo.bytes;

            var aRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle;
            var aRead:BitReader = new BitReader(aBytes, 8);
            var perEntry:uint = aRead.readUnsigned(5);

            aRect.left   = aRead.readSigned(perEntry) / 20;
            aRect.right  = aRead.readSigned(perEntry) / 20;
            aRect.top    = aRead.readSigned(perEntry) / 20;
            aRect.bottom = aRead.readSigned(perEntry) / 20;

            aRead.dispose();
            aRead = null;

            trace(aRect);
        }
    }
}

import flash.utils.ByteArray;

internal class BitReader
{
    private var bytes:ByteArray;
    private var position:int;
    private var bits:String;

    public function BitReader(source:ByteArray, start:int)
    {
        bits = "";
        bytes = source;
        position = start;
    }

    public function readSigned(length:int):int
    {
        var aSign:int = (readBits(1) == "1")? -1: 1;

        return aSign * int(readUnsigned(length - 1));
    }

    public function readUnsigned(length:int):uint
    {
        return parseInt(readBits(length), 2);
    }

    private function readBits(length:int):String
    {
        while (length > bits.length) readAhead();

        var result:String = bits.substr(0, length);

        bits = bits.substr(length);

        return result;
    }

    static private const Z:String = "00000000";

    private function readAhead():void
    {
        var wasBits:String = bits;

        var aByte:String = bytes[position].toString(2);

        bits += Z.substr(aByte.length) + aByte;

        position++;
    }

    public function dispose():void
    {
        bits = null;
        bytes = null;
    }
}
```